# Label with textvariable not showing up

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Label "totalresults" in window "root2" is not showing up. I would like to that text label to update every time button is pressed in first window and calculate the amount of those button presses.

```
     #create the window
     root = Tk()
     root2 = Tk()


     #probability calculations
     totalrolls = tk.StringVar()
     amountofrolls = 0

     #update numbers in gui
        def add_num():
        global amountofrolls
        amountofrolls += 1
        totalrolls.set("Amount of rolls made in total: " +str(amountofrolls))


#button functions
def button_press():
  add_num()

#string variable
totalrolls.set("Amount of rolls made in total: " + str(amountofrolls))

#modify second window
todennäköisyys = Label(root2, text="The quantity of results:")
totalresults = Label (root2, textvariable=totalrolls)

todennäköisyys.pack()
totalresults.pack()
#kick off the event loop
    root.mainloop()
    root2.mainloop()
```

I am not getting any errors or anything the second window just dosent show the label.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. However, right away there is a very glaring problem - you should never create more than one instance of `Tk`, and definitely never call `mainloop` more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You should not start more than one instance of `Tk()`. Use `Toplevel()` instead. See example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()     # create the window
display = Toplevel(root)

#probability calculations
totalrolls = StringVar()
amountofrolls = 0

def add_num():  # update numbers in gui
    global amountofrolls
    amountofrolls += 1
    totalrolls.set("Amount of rolls made in total: " + str(amountofrolls))

def button_press(): # button functions
    add_num()

#string variable
totalrolls.set("Amount of rolls made in total: " + str(amountofrolls))

#modify second window
todennäköisyys = Label(display, text="The quantity of results:")
totalresults = Label (display, textvariable=totalrolls)
todennäköisyys.pack()
totalresults.pack()

# Create button in root window
Button(root, text='Increase number', command=add_num).pack()

#kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```